# cakephp new item notification system

Tags: sql, cakephp

I'm trying to create a cakephp website which has a notification system telling people when they log in how many new items they have.

I currently have the site logging every time a visitor logs into the site however I am unsure how I can compare date/timestamps against each other  in a find.

What the find should do is return all data that has a newer timestamp when compared to the persons previous loggedIn.created

I am unsure how to code this/just trying to figure out a concept on how I can code this. any help or direction would be appreciated.

To make this simple a

`user hasMany logIns`

```
logIns belongsTo user
```

a `user hasMany Invoices`

```
Invoices belongTo user

user has id, name, account_id

loggedin has id, created, user_id

invoice has id, sender, receiver, created, account_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the normal comparison operators < and > with dates and datetimes.

- > means "after"
- < means "before"

To find invoices that have been created after a login date in a CakePHP controller, you could write for example:

```
$previous_login = '2012-09-20'; # obtain from somewhere
$new_invoices = $this->Invoice->find('all', array(
    # "created after previous login"
    'conditions' => array('created >' => $previos_login)
));
```

Comment: +1, this is one good approach; but depending on how the app is set up, after logging in, the `$last_login` could in fact be the "current" login. just something to consider if OP updates the `last_login` immediately after the login action.

Comment: Right, I guess I should have named the variable "previous login".